How can I properly use blur to multiple elements with an exception of one using javascript
Is there a way to blur the all the background elements except the clicked box. Reason why the background element needed to be blurred is that I want the clicked box to be the focal point.
I tried some Javascript like
if (div.firstChild && div.firstChild.classList.contains('container')) {
      renderBoxes(div.firstChild);
}

And so on. but it doesn't work properly as I intended.
My expected is to blur the blue, pink backgrounds and the other boxes that are not clicked.


function applyStyles(element, styles) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
    element.style[key] = value;
  }
}

let currentlyClickedBox = null;

function renderBoxes(container) {
  let numberOfBoxes = boxes.length;
  let additionalXValue = 500 - (9 - numberOfBoxes) * 10;
  let offsetValue = 40;
  let offsetAdditional = 0;

  // Loop through tokens array
  boxes.forEach(token => {
    // Create a new div for each token
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = token.class;
    applyStyles(div, token.style);

    // Add additional offset to each token
    div.setAttribute('data-offset-additional', offsetAdditional);

    // Add click event listener to each token
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Check if another token was previously clicked
      if (currentlyClickedBox && currentlyClickedBox !== div) {
        // Reset previously clicked token
        currentlyClickedBox.style.transform = 'none';
        currentlyClickedBox.style.position = "relative";
      }

      // Check if this token is currently clicked
      if (currentlyClickedBox === div) {
        // Reset clicked token
        currentlyClickedBox.style.transform = 'none';
        currentlyClickedBox.style.position = "relative";
        currentlyClickedBox = null;
      } else {
        const translateXValue = -div.getBoundingClientRect().x; // Get the px distance of right corner to token;

        // (Adjust token to center) - (Offset of each token) 
        const translateXOffset = (translateXValue + additionalXValue) - (offsetValue + parseInt(div.getAttribute('data-offset-additional')));

        // Transform clicked token
        currentlyClickedBox = div;

        div.style.transform = `translate(${translateXOffset}px, -350px) rotateY(180deg) scale(3)`;
      }
    });

    // Append token div to container
    container.appendChild(div);
    offsetAdditional = offsetAdditional + 20; // Increment additional offset each token
  });
}

function renderForeignObjects() {
  const svg = document.getElementById('mySvg');

  foreignObjects.forEach(obj => {
    const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
    foreignObject.setAttribute('x', obj.x);
    foreignObject.setAttribute('y', obj.y);
    foreignObject.setAttribute('width', obj.width);
    foreignObject.setAttribute('height', obj.height);

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = obj.content;
    applyStyles(div.firstChild, obj.style);

    if (div.firstChild && div.firstChild.classList.contains('container')) {
      renderBoxes(div.firstChild);
    }

    foreignObject.appendChild(div);
    svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
  });
}

const foreignObjects = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    content: '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></div>',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    content: '<div></div>',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "pink"
    }
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 300,
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    content: '<div></div>',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "pink"
    }
  },
  {
    // Whole page
    x: 100,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 750,
    content: '<div class="container"></div>',
    style: {}
  }
];

const boxes = [{
    y: -50,
    class: "box",
    style: {
      width: "110px",
      height: "110px",
      margin: "0 5px",
      backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }
  },
  {
    class: "box",
    style: {
      width: "110px",
      height: "110px",
      margin: "0 5px",
      backgroundColor: "#ddd"
    }
  },
  {
    class: "box",
    style: {
      width: "110px",
      height: "110px",
      margin: "0 5px",
      backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }
  }
];

// Call the function to render foreign objects
renderForeignObjects();
.a {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
<svg id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="a p" viewBox="0 0 1200 800"></svg>




How does currentlyClickedBox get updated? You need to call renderBoxes() again after it's called so you can take it into account.

You mean blur as in #mySvg { filter: blur(12px); }

Your current SVG contains only <foreignObject> and no native svg elements - why the svg wrapper?  A HTML/CSS-only approach may be better. Besides, it doesn't render in iOS safari - prone to foreignObject rendering issues.

you can do it with this algorithm:

Assign a class to box's container showing that one box is active e.g. active

Assign another class to the currently active box e.g. focused

now use this additional css to your code:


.container.active box:not(.focused) {
    filter: blur(5px);
}

css above means :"when container is active, blur every box that is not the focused one"

Hope it helped. ^_^
